# I bought a domain name, and now

Tags: heroku, dns, google-domain-api

I bought a domain name on Google, and now I can't figure out how to get my heroku app to that address.

Specifically, the person who I am building a site for purchased the domain. How can I convince heroku that I (we) own that domain??

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In heroku go to tag 'Setting' then add domain that you bought from google.

Then in google domain, config it point to domain of heroku. ex: youapp-system.herokuapp.com

If you don't know your domain in heroku, just click to menu on the corner top-right, and 'open app'

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! The issue is when I try to add a domain, I receive this error: "Domain "designstatements-llc.com" could not be created:
Please verify your account in order to add domains (please enter a credit card)"...(which doesn't make sense because I haven't bought a domain through heroku)